# SOLR malformed query generates problems

Tags: solr

Does anyone else see weird solr behavior when you malform the URL a bit? Like

```
 http://server:9000/solr/collections/handler?qqqqqqqqqqqq=text
```

My CPU jumps to 100% and system hangs... sometimes index corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a query handler you are hitting, and you didn't provide a "q",
you're probably getting whatever defaults are configured (perhaps q=*:*) and that is taking up a lot of CPU.

Comment: Hi Yonik, I actually have a well a different request handler that works fine, response time is great, but if I add this, I there is some ...hm.. unpredictable behavior. Did you try to run this in your environment?